Powers of two, fibonacci numbers
I've come across many proofs which prove the assertion that no Fibonacci number $F_a \geq 16$, can be expressed as a power of two $2^k$. However, the proofs I have found are more complex than this one, so I am confident that I have made an error, although I am unsure where it lies. I would be grateful for any assistance in resolving this issue.
It can be shown that:
$$ \gcd(F_{12}, F_a) = \gcd(16 \cdot 9,2^k) = 16 = F_{\gcd(12,a)} $$
This is a contradiction, since $16$ is not a Fibonacci number.
Thanks a lot.

There are several ways to prove it. Taking of the GCD is expressed in this answer, albeit done in a different manner. $\quad$ A similar approach is that $ 2 \mid F_n \Leftrightarrow n = 3k$, and then $ F_k \mid F_{3k}$ so we just have to check a few starting values.

@CalvinLin Thank you, I didn't completely understand the proof linked in that answer so I guessed the one-liner wasn't correct.

Hm, you know what, I don't think that top solution is true, despite the 38 upvotes with no downvotes (I just added mine in). There's a comment indicating potential issues. $\quad$ In any case, your solution works.

@CalvinLin oh well, a lesson for me to triple-check answers no matter how well received they are
